# Candidate Questions for Migration to CS.SE

Tags: discussion, migration

Do you think the following question would be a suitable question on CS.SE?
Do you think it should be migrated to here?

Comment: From cstheory:
[Given the set of length of triangle, find the Maximum Area Triangle](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19974/given-the-set-of-length-of-triangle-find-the-maximum-area-triangle)

Comment: I think it's suitable, but why migrate? It seems to have been accepted by at least some [cstheory.SE] users.

Comment: @Raphael, because it is undergrad homework level.

Answer (score 4):

[I've already stated my position on migrations from CSTheory.SE to CS.SE](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/please-dont-migrate-bad-questions-to-cs-stack-exchange/2714#2714). I think the CSTheory community and moderators are competent to make this decision. If it's a reasonable-looking computer science question whose fault on CSTheory.SE is only that it isn't research-level enough or that it isn't theoretical enough, go ahead and migrate. (But remember that programming questions go on SO.)

Go ahead and migrate responsibly. If we don't like a question, we'll close it and reject the migration.

I personally do not intend to monitor this thread.

Comment: I don't have time to monitor or check to see if there is a duplicate question or if there is a reference question, that is why I am asking.

Comment: @Kaveh It doesn't matter if there's a duplicate question. Migrate, and leave the duplicate search to the CS.SE community. On the monitoring thing… your way requires you to monitor the responses here, it's self-imposed work. I don't relish having to check back on the response on meta.cstheory myself.

Comment: Some of the complaints about previous migrations that I got were about what I wrote above (this is explicitly stated in [D.W.'s question](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/)). That is why I am asking as [Raphael wrote](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2712/please-dont-migrate-bad-questions-to-cs-stack-exchange#comment6706_2714) (I don't see much difference between asking on meta in place of chat, it is just simpler for me to ask on meta). I can check later to see if people think the question is suitable for migration and then migrate it if it is so.

Comment: @Kaveh: [Gilles' proposal](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/2714/1546) gives a clear answer for the question we talk about here: it's a valid CS question and includes some own thoughts. Therefore, it's (likely to be) fine for [cs.SE], so no reason not to migrate. I never understood your reaction to the earlier discussion (to not migrate at all); frankly, I thought you were overreacting.

Comment: @Raphael, I understand Gilles' answer. But from my perspective I see that there is a general and strong opposition to the way that I was migrating questions to here, obviously I don't want to continue that when it is creating so much negative reaction. Why make so many users here and there unhappy by continuing those migrations? On the other hand I don't think I have time to migrate questions following what people seem to expect by checking the criteria myself. That is why I am asking. As I said I don't think it is much different from asking in the chat. It is just simpler for me.

Answer (score 1):

Is the following question suitable for migration to CS.SE?

[Examples of context-free languages with a non-context-free complements](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/20091/)

Comment: Seems like a good one for migration to me!